# Use ion-infinite-scroll to begin at bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular7

I'm making a message feed and I want my users to be able to scroll up to see their messages.

I can now scroll (even if it jumps after a new message load), but my page begins at the top of my view.

The first message is at the total bottom of the view, and I would like my users to see their last message. However, the infinite-scroll starts on top.

**messaging-interface.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <custom-toolbar class="menu-bar" [title]=chatRoomType>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      {{chatRoomType}}
    </ion-title>
  </custom-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="message-interface">
  <ion-infinite-scroll position="top" (ionInfinite)="loadMoreMessages($event)" id="scroller">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="circles" (change)="scrollTop($event)" id="scrollerContent">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>

  <ion-grid class="message-grid" id="msgGrid">
    <ion-col class="message-grid" size="12">
      <app-message-bubble *ngFor="let messageAct of displayedMessages.reverse()" [messageModel]="messageAct"></app-message-bubble>
    </ion-col>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <app-message-bar (sendButtonClicked)="onMessageSent($event)"></app-message-bar>
</ion-footer>
```

**messaging-interface.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { ChatMessage } from "../ChatMessage.model"
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ChatroomResolver } from "../chatroom-service/i-chatroom-service"
import { MockMessageService } from "../message-service/mock-message.service"

import * as moment from 'moment';
import { IonInfiniteScroll } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messaging-interface',
  templateUrl: './messaging-interface.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messaging-interface.page.scss'],
})
export class MessagingInterfacePage implements OnInit {
  public displayedMessages: Array<ChatMessage>;

  private chatRoomResolver: ChatroomResolver;
  private gatherer: MockMessageService;
  private actualRoute: ActivatedRoute;
  private chatRoomId: string;
  private chatRoomType: string;

  @ViewChild(IonInfiniteScroll) scroller: IonInfiniteScroll;

  constructor(gatherer: MockMessageService, actualRoute: ActivatedRoute, chatRoomResolver: ChatroomResolver) {
    this.gatherer = gatherer;
    this.chatRoomResolver = chatRoomResolver;
    this.actualRoute = actualRoute;
    this.displayedMessages = new Array<ChatMessage>();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chatRoomType = this.actualRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("type");
    let matchId: string = this.actualRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("matchId");
    this.chatRoomId = this.chatRoomResolver.getAssociatedChatRoom(this.chatRoomType, matchId);
    console.log(this.chatRoomType + " " + matchId + " " + this.chatRoomId);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("PostInit");
    let msgGrid = <HTMLElement> document.getElementById("msgGrid");
    msgGrid.scrollIntoView(false);
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.displayedMessages = new Array<ChatMessage>();
    this.gatherer.resetGatherer();
    this.gatherer.loadMessages(10).subscribe(messages =>
      this.displayedMessages = messages);
  }

  onMessageSent(sent: string) {
    let sentMessage = new ChatMessage(sent, "envoyeur", moment(), false);
    this.displayedMessages.push(sentMessage);
  }

  loadMoreMessages(event: Event) {
    let target = <HTMLIonInfiniteScrollElement> event.target;
    this.gatherer.loadMessages(10).subscribe(messages => {
      for (let msg of messages)
        this.displayedMessages.push(msg);
        target.complete();
    });
  }

  scrollTop(event: Event) {
    console.log("Scroll top");
    let target = <HTMLIonInfiniteScrollElement> event.target;
    target.scrollTo(0, (<HTMLElement> target.firstChild.lastChild).offsetTop);
  }
}
```

**Solutions I tried**

- I tried to use the `HTMLElement`'s `scrollTo` function, `scrollToView` (still on the code).
- I tried the ngx-infinite-scroller npm package, didn't work at all.

**I have two questions**

1. *The most important : how could I force my infinite-scroller to start at bottom ?*
2. *How can I prevent my scroller to have the mini "jump" effect when loading messages ?*

If my question seems unclear, feel free to help me to improve it.

Comment: Might be worth checking your versions of ionic etc. They seems to have built this feature for the soul purpose of achieving what you're trying to do. https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/8099. There is mention of `scrollDownOnLoad` so it sounds like it should work in conjunction with `position='top'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Content component to handle scrolling in code and use `scrollToTop()`

For more info see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content#scrollToTop

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export class MyPage{
  @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

  scrollToTop() {
    this.content.scrollToTop();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use infinite scroll.

Just set the position attribute to top, so it works the way you need.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/infinite-scroll